# Omega theme meta tag problem on Google

Tags: 7, javascript, theming, meta-tags

I'm using Omega theme. But when search my site on Google, description is site menu items. I want change this area via spesific word.

So, open my template.php file and add this codes:

```
function site_page_alter($page) {
   $meta_description = array(
            '#type' => 'My Site Desc',
            '#tag' => 'My Site Desc',
            '#attributes' => array(
                'name' => 'My Site Desc',
                'content' =>  'My Site Desc'
            )
   );


drupal_add_html_head( $meta_description, 'My Site Desc' );
}

function manualMetaTags($path) {
    $description = "My Site Desc";
    $keywords    = "My Site Desc";
    print "<meta name='description' content='".$description."' />\n";
    print "<meta name='keywords' content='".$keywords."' />\n";
}
```

And add main.js:

```
<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
<?php manualMetaTags($_GET['q']); ?>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

After, send sitemap to Google. My description is seen but with menu items.

E.G.

My site desc on Google:

MAIN - NEWS - CONTACT

When add codes:

My Site Desc MAIN - NEWS - CONTACT

But i want only seen My Site Desc. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not really your decision to make...Google will take what it feels is the best representation of your site's description, whether that be the meta description tag or some text from elsewhere in the body.

The best you can do is make sure that you have `<meta name="robots" content="noodp">`   (which [Google supports](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-supports-meta-noodp-tag/)) somewhere in the document `<head>`. That will at least mean your title/description will come from somewhere in your page source, and not from the Open Directory Project (which is a distinct possibility otherwise).

The most important thing...don't expect instant results. Google will revisit your site when it's ready, and there's still no guarantee it will use exactly the text you want it to for the SERP description.

If you're not happy with that outcome, contact an SEO specialist who might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Clive said, Google picks a text based on search input. If the user's keyword is in the meta description, the description will be displayed. If the user's keyword isn't in the meta description, Google will assemble a text from the page from top to bottom.

**However**:

In your case you could try to position the content before the menus and then display it the other way round with CSS. This way, when Google assembles a text it will take a snippet from the content, not the menu. This is the way Wikipedia does it (disable CSS to see it).

Comment: Still problem...

Comment: Can you give me the link to your website? It might take a while until Google has crawled your page.

Comment: my link: http://bit.ly/OaeSJb

Comment: The problem is that you don't have any text on the frontpage that Google can use to assemble a text from except for the menu. The only real option I see is to add text before the menu.

Comment: In front? but i dont want like this text.

Comment: Then there is no other option I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the words in your description tag to prevent Google from assembling other word from the web page content to fill up the description area. and wait until the next crawling to see the result.